# Python: Histogram with range, but distribution is calculated for whole set

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, probability-density

I'm using the matplotlib to draw a pdf histogram and need to use the *range* variable due to the appearance of the graph. Got a high in the start and in the end, the probability chance is so much higher for these peaks so the rest of the graph can't be seen so I need to use *range* to 'zoom' in. But when *range* is used probability density will only consider the data within the *range*.

Is there a way to continue using *range* but the probability density is calculated not only with the data in the given *range* but all data?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm plotting the pdf of packet sizes for a data set. The graph have peaks in the lower region ~100 bytes and at the upper region ~1450 bytes. To show the distribution in the middle of the data set I use range to zoom in different areas which gives better detail for the distribution.

```
ax.hist(x=list_of_pkt_sizes,bins=25,density=True,range=[500,1000])
```

This is an example of code snippet used to plot one of the zoomed in areas. As said above it now only shows the distribution for given range. I want the overall distribution.

Comment: Please provide the code used to generate your PDF. It seems to me that you should be able to provide the a restricted sequence of `bins=` instead of using `range=` but it's hard to be sure without data to experiment with. Please refer to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added code snippet plus some more clarification. See edit

Comment: Is the problem simply with the *visualization* of the histogram? If so, could you just change the x-axis limits (`plt.xlim(500,1000)`) to only show the region that you are interested in?

Comment: That's a good point @DizietAsahi. The only issue is choosing the appropriate number of bins

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could quite easily normalise manually:

```
import numpy as np

# Convert list to numpy array for convenience
pkt_arr = np.array(list_of_pkt_sizes)

# Set range variables
min_range, max_range = 500, 1000

# Filter out elements not in range to new array
pkt_arr_in_range = pkt_arr[(pkt_arr > min_range) & (pkt_arr < max_range)]

# Get normalisers - bin size and total number of elements
num_elem_norm = pkt_arr.shape[0]
counts, bins = np.histogram(x=pkt_arr_in_range, bins=25)
bin_width = bins[1] - bins[0]

# Get x coordinates of LHS of bins
xs = bins[:-1]

# Normalise counts (prob density per unit of input)
counts_norm = counts / (num_elem_norm * bin_width)

# Use bar chart
ax.bar(xs, counts_norm, width=bin_width, align='edge')
```

**UPDATE:** @DizietAsahi makes a better suggestion in their comment:

```
min_range, max_range = 500, 1000
min_all, max_all = min(list_of_pkt_sizes), max(list_of_pkt_sizes)
range_ratio = (max_all - min_all) / (max_range - min_range)
ax.hist(list_of_pkt_sizes, bins=int(round(25 * range_ratio)), density=True)
plt.xlim(min_range, max_range)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would tackle the problem. I've generated a fake distribution with large numbers of low and high values as per your information

```
plt.figure()
plt.hist(l1, density=True, bins=25)
```

[image]

I use the `numpy.histogram` function to obtain the density distribution. Notice that I use a custom `bins=` argument: I request one bin from 0-500, 25 bins between 500 and 1000 and 1 bin between 1000 and 2000

```
p,b = np.histogram(l1, density=True, bins=[0]+list(np.linspace(500,1000,25+1))+[2000])
```

[image]

Finally, I use matplotlib's `bar()` function to plot the resulting histogram, but I simply omit the first and last bin

```
plt.figure()
plt.bar(x=b[1:-2], height=p[1:-1], width=20, align='edge')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this looks like a solution to my problem. I have a lot on my plate so it might take some days before I can test it, but I will make sure to mark it as a solution if it works!